# Get labels as column values instead of numeric value

Tags: r, label

I imported a sav file with a lot of columns that are labelled. Instead of labelled data, I would like to get the labels as values.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(color = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1), 
                                       label = "color", 
                                       format.spss = "F1.0", 
                                       labels = c(`blue` = 1, `yellow` = 2, `pink` = 3), 
                                       class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), 
                row.names = c(NA,-10L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# color
# 1      1
# 2      1
# 3      1
# 4      1
# 5      2
# 6      3
# 7      2
# 8      1
# 9      1
# 10     1
```

What I would like to get

```
# color
# 1   blue
# 2   blue
# 3   blue
# 4   blue
# 5 yellow
```

I've been looking for hours, but only find ways to remove the labels which results in a df with the numeric values and the labels completely gone (basically the first df in this post, without label information). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `haven::as_factor` is what you need?

It also works with the core tidyverse packages loaded i.e. `library(tidyverse)` and using the `as_factor` function. I suspect loading the `tidyverse` installs functions from `haven`, including the `as_factor` function.

```r
haven::as_factor(df)

#> # A tibble: 10 x 1
#>    color 
#>    <fct> 
#>  1 blue  
#>  2 blue  
#>  3 blue  
#>  4 blue  
#>  5 yellow
#>  6 pink  
#>  7 yellow
#>  8 blue  
#>  9 blue  
#> 10 blue
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>